# add library to your project in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new to Android

I want to use this library [Material Design Android Library](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary)

how can I use this library in my project, I read docs but I didn't understood.

Comment: What have you tried? What exactly don't you understand? Please try to ask directed and specific questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**STEPS TO INCLUDE LIBRARY**

```
1.Open your android studio project
2.Click Scripts Gradle(Left appears)
2.Go to build.gradle (Module: app)
3.Add this library in dependences section with this line:
   compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.5@aar'
4.Click Sync Now.
5.Now you can  add material design elements as it appears on the website of   the library.
```

**Example:
Button Material Design**

gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "co.com.witz.materialdesign"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.5@aar'
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
    }
}
```

main_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:materialdesign="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonFlat
        android:id="@+id/buttonflat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#1E88E5"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**RESULT**

[Material Design Button Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObUut.png)

If what you want is to use more material design elements I leave the link to a large compendium Github you can use easily.

> https://github.com/wasabeef/awesome-android-ui

Answer (score 3):

Try the following steps,

1. Create the libs folder in the root directory if you dont have one.
2. copy your library project into this folder.
3. now add this library in your settings.gradle with the following command:

`include ':libs:<libarary project name>'`

4. go to your build.gradle file of your AppProject and add the following line to your 'dependencies':

`compile project(':libs:<libarary project name>')`

5. at least you have to sync your gradle files: Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle Files

This should work :)

Answer (score 1):

First you need to make a jar file out of this project. Some libraries contain a jar file in advance, but if it doesn't, you should open Android Studio, hit "import project" and select the relevant folder/gradle file.

Once the jar is ready, put it in you app\libs folder (if it doesn't exist, create one). Then hit File --> Project Structure --> select your app in the modules list --> Dependencies --> plus icon --> file dependency --> select your jar file.

**EDIT**:

The method above is relevant for private libraries and for those that aren't on Maven. Most libraries nowadays are on Maven Central so you just need to add their dependency to your `app.gradle` file. For example:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.5@aar'
}
```